# How Does Angular Momentum Affect the Angle of Reflection of a Puck Bouncing Off a Wall?

Tags: angular-momentum, friction, collision

I am trying to understand the relationship between angular momentum and the angle of reflection when a puck bounces off a wall. More specifically, I am curious about the role that the coefficient of friction between the puck and the wall plays in influencing the bounce direction.

Here is a scenario I am considering: A puck with a certain angular momentum hits a wall and bounces off. During the collision, the puck exerts a force on the wall and vice versa. I am inclined to think that the rotational motion of the puck generates a friction force, akin to how a car tire interacts with the road, leading to a change in the velocity vector parallel to the wall.

Could someone clarify if my understanding is correct? Are there specific limits or thresholds to how significantly the velocity can be affected by these factors? Any insights or references to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Friction is parallel to the wall, not perpendicular.

Comment: you're right, my bad typo